# Build warnings vs IntelliSense warnings

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, warnings, intellisense

I just joined a company with legacy code.
The build has over 10000 warnings.
90% of the warnings are "obsolete" warnings.
My coworkers don't want me to disable those warnings, because it is useful for them in IntelliSense.

My question is: is there a practical way, where I can still see the warning in the editor in Visual Studio, but it does not show up in the build.log?

Comment: I wonder how exactly they are useful for them if they still ignore them all?

Comment: There pops up a warning if they want to use an obsolete method in the CURRENT file. That's why they don't want me to remove the warning

Comment: What about using `#pragma warning disable` in the legacy code? It is not good to keep for many reasons. For starters, how will you find new warnings in the sea of legacy warnings?

Comment: @Sefe exactly. There are some 15-30 warnings and nobody notices, when new warnings are introduced. Using #pragma warning disable is an option, but i would need to edit 4000 files, which is not fun at all :( I was hoping there would be an easier solution

Comment: Have you thought about a tool that automatically adds the pragma to legacy files? Shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: @tevlon84, Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT thank you. i accepted your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a practical way, where i can still see the warning in the editor in visual studio, but it does not show up in the build.log?

Since you can not disable those warnings and using `#pragma warning disable` is not your option, I would like provide your a workaround to resolve this question.

You can managed to supress the warning level with `/p:WarningLevel=X` with MSBuild command line.

For example, when I build the sample project from Visual Studio, there is a warining in the error list window:

[image]

Then I build it with MSBuild command line with property `/p:WarningLevel=0` in the command line:

```
msbuild "YourProjectName" /fl /flp:logfile=D:\MyProjectOutput.log;verbosity=diagnostic /p:WarningLevel=0
```

The meaning of the level:

```
Warning  
Level    Meaning
-------- -------------------------------------------
      0  Turns off emission of all warning messages.

      1  Displays severe warning messages

      2  Displays level 1 warnings plus certain, less-severe warnings, such
         as warnings about hiding class members

      3  Displays level 2 warnings plus certain, less-severe warnings, such 
         as warnings about expressions that always evaluate to true or false

      4  (the default) Displays all level 3 warnings plus informational warnings
```

[image]

There is no warining in the build log, then open the log file, there is also no warning here:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there a way to just disable intellisense warnings in the editor? I tried to disable intellisense but its warning are still showing up in the editor!

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to switch between the build configurations "Debug" and "Release". So you will be able to have a "clean" build.log when compiling the "Release" but still have the warnings when working with a "Debug" build:
[image]

And when working yourself you just need to uncheck the warnings in the error list panel:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Some basic SWDev logic here:

If a warning is useful, then it should be fixed as a bug (perhaps a minor one) would be.
If a warning isn't useful, then it should be suppressed to keep the build clean, so that useful warnings show up.

Ultimately, with project schedules and management pressure, there may be no way to get technical debt like that reduced to the point where it is manageable. But disabling a correct and useful warning is a very bad idea (especially suppressing an obsolete warning - the next upgrade of the associated component will cause the product to stop working, with an unexpected amount of work to fix it).

What we typically used to do with these sorts of things, where I worked, was get them prioritised as a task on the development schedule - we'd have a meeting, decide on which issues were significant (which warnings to go after, which to suppress etc...), and batch them into a number of tasks, with an appropriate prioritisation.